# django logging config with gunicorn and command line scripts

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

Up until now this config

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
}
```

was good enough for me, everything to console then using `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE` and gunicorn config

```py
bind = "0.0.0.0:50000"
workers = 1
worker_class = "gthread"
threads = 2
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 60
keepalive = 5
accesslog = "/var/log/gunicorn/myapp.com-access.log"
errorlog = "/var/log/gunicorn/myapp.com-error.log"
loglevel = "debug"
capture_output = True
```

everything went to accesslog or errorLog.

Now that I need to use `poetry run python manage.py sqlflush` I run into trouble.
all my logger.info() logs are also output to console so I get

```
Logging in
Logged in
Logging in
Already logged in
BEGIN;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE `myapp_imagemodel`;
TRUNCATE `auth_user_groups`;
TRUNCATE `auth_user_user_permissions`;
TRUNCATE `auth_permission`;
TRUNCATE `auth_group_permissions`;
TRUNCATE `auth_user`;
TRUNCATE `auth_group`;
TRUNCATE `django_content_type`;
TRUNCATE `myapp_game`;
TRUNCATE `myapp_game_screenshots`;
TRUNCATE `django_session`;
TRUNCATE `django_admin_log`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
COMMIT;
```

How should I configure logging so it doesn't mess up with manage.py script's output?
Can I still have it all in one file?

Answer (score 0):

if you are fine with not having SQL print to your terminal you can disable the logging for database backend

```
'handlers': {
     'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.NullHandler',
      },
},
'loggers': {
     'django.db.backends': { # disable database logging
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level':'DEBUG',
      },
 }
```

Comment: The point is to have ONLY SQL printed to terminal, so I can run the sqlflush command. In the end I made each info, warning, debug level go to their own files.